# cvDiv c++ with IplImage (float)

Tags: c++, opencv

I need to divide per element an IplImage for another one.
if I use 3 IPL_DEPTH_8U image it works, but if I use 3 IPL_DEPTH_32F image I get an error Cv::Exception at memory location...
the code is just 
cvDiv(im1, im2, im3);
I'm sure about the 3 images, the error is in cvDiv

Comment: They all need to have the same type and size.

Comment: Could you post the complete relevant section of code you are using?

Answer (score 0):

**They all need to have the same type and size and must be single-channel.**

`cvDiv()` works on arrays, which means that if your images have more than 1 channel, you will have to repeat this operation individually for each channel for it to work.

What's happening is that most probably when your images are `IPL_DEPTH_8U` they are storing grayscale images, meaning single channel. That's why it works.

When they are `IPL_DEPTH_32F` they are probably colored, meaning they have 3 channels (RGB). That's why you are getting the error.

If you want to know how to work with each channel individually, [check this message](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/46711).

Comment: they are single channel.. but I solved it by creating my own Div function I think is way easier than try to fix cvDiv, still thank you

Comment: Ok. In the future, post the OpenCV version you are using.